# Renewal of token in ADAL is inconsistent.(Aurelia)

Tags: webpack, token, aurelia, access-token, adal

I am using **adal.js** (1.0.15) in an aurelia based SPA. I have changed the default offset of two minutes to 3 minutes and used a window. `setInterval` method to call for token renewal every one minute. According to my understanding when we call `AcquireToken()` it first looks into the browser cache by using `getCachedUser()`. This will look for the `id_token` and return a non null user. But it doesn't check the token expiration time though. But between the time it requests for a new token and it gets the response, the token expiry time shows 0 (in the browser console). The older token however stays in the browser cache until the new one is received.

Hence in my application at times it refreshes the token and at times it fails the very first time.

As far as I know between the request and response for a new token from AAD, if the time exceeds 6 secs then adal sends timeout error. Is it this error that is the reason for the the failure or renewal of token?

Can someone suggest how can we handle the inconsistency?

Also when the token is renewed there is no callback handler. So i have also used `handleWindowCallback()`.

Answer (score 0):

The token expiration check happens [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/703e560f26de90fef9ae955529605672242c1f71/lib/adal.js#L417-L419) in the `getCachedToken()` called by `AcquireToken()`. 
There are many reasons token renewal could fail. Please see some of these and the possible ways to handle listed in this [FAQ](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs#q7-token-renewal-operation-failed-due-to-timeout).